# How to set persistent git credentials on a Windows host using Ansible?

Tags: git, ansible

I need to clone a repository on a Windows host remotely using Ansible and have the git credentials stay persistent on the host, at least for some amount of time. I'm using Ansible Automation Platform.

Here's the way we currently do it:

```
git clone https://user:password@my-git-server.com/path/to/repo.git --branch my-branch
```

This works fine, but then if I need to have Ansible go back in and pull changes, etc. it fails:

> fatal: Failed to enumerate credentials. [0x520] fatal: A specified logon session does not exist.

Despite the fact that I have `credential.helper` set to `store`, somehow the credentials I provided during `git clone` weren't stored. This also causes problems with submodules since, for whatever reason, those credentials aren't being passed through to the submodules that are cloned along with my repo.

I'm unable to use `credential.helper wincred` because the `community.windows.win_credential` module fails without `become`, and `become` fails due to the error I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77643399/createprocessasuser-failed-with-win32errorcode-1058-when-running-become-true-on), which is also detailed by someone else in [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69086).

I tried using `credential.helper cache`, but received this error:

> credential-cache is disabled in this build of Git

I can, of course, manually go in and clone with my credentials which are then stored but this doesn't solve my problem of cloning remotely/programmatically via Ansible.

So I have yet to find a viable option for storing persistent credentials. I can clone a repo once using the `user:password` method I listed earlier, but outside of that I haven't found a way to accomplish this.

Alternatively, if there's a way I can provide the credentials each time I interact with the repo, that'll work as well. Like if I already have the repo cloned and need to go back in and do a `git pull`, that would also work.

Of course the `wincred` method seems to be the most secure so that would be preferred, but since it's not an option, any method that would get this working is appreciated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have opted out of using an ssh key pair?

Comment: We're using a central service account to clone and it's not possible to set it up with ssh keys due to the way my organization has it set up